# Managing multiple Times Series with Crosstalk and plotly

Tags: r, r-plotly

I am trying to have a dynamic graph using plotly with crosstalk to show multiple times series. Depending on if a checkbox if checked or not, I would like the time series to be display on the graph or not.
In the code below, I created two times series 1 and 2 in the same dataframe (df_final).
I have two issues so far:

- When none of the checkbox is checked, there is still a time series on
  the graph
- When both of the checkboxes are checked, instead of showing two times
  series, the code considers that only 1 unique time series.

I don’t know how to improve any of the above, any ideas?

Also, I am not sure I am using the right tools (crosstalk, etc). Any other suggestions are welcomed.

```
library(plotly)
library(crosstalk)

#Create two identical dataframe
df_1 <- economics
df_2 <- economics

#Add a key to each dataframe to dissociate the two time series
df_1$ts <- 1
df_2$ts <- 2

#Modify the first dataframe
df_2$psavert <- economics$psavert + 1

df_final <- rbind(df_1, df_2)

shared_df_final <- SharedData$new(df_final)

bscols(
       list(filter_checkbox("Time series", "Time series", shared_df_final, ~ts, inline = TRUE)),
       plot_ly(data = shared_df_final, x = ~date, height = 700) %>%
         add_lines(y = ~df_final$psavert, line = list(color = "#00526d", width = 1),
                   hoverinfo = "text", text = "ts")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that instead:

```
plot_ly() %>%
  add_lines(data = df_1, x= ~date, y = ~psavert, name = "First") %>%
  add_lines(data = df_2, x= ~date, y = ~psavert, name = "Second") %>%
  layout(
    updatemenus = list(
      list(
        y = 0.8,
        type= 'buttons',
        buttons = list(
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, TRUE)),
               label = "Both"),
          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(TRUE, FALSE)),
               label = "First"),

          list(method = "restyle",
               args = list("visible", list(FALSE, TRUE)),
               label = "Second")))
    )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! This kind of works, but I was looking for two check buttons instead of three as in the future I will have to manage up to 5-6 time series on the same plot. Any better ideas?

Comment: It can be a dropdown button also

Comment: A dropdown button will not be ideal. I am looking for a checkboxInput (display or do not display) per time series. If I have 5 time series, I can manage with 5 check buttons. A dropdown menu will have 5^2 = 25 lines instead.

Comment: @Liky, From the example above, you can remove the `both` label if you want. But at the beginning, all traces will be displayed and after that only the trace you selected will be displayed.